# Python __name__ behavior with mutliprocessing and PyInstaller

Tags: python, multiprocessing, freeze

I am experiencing a behavior that I was not expecting, and I wonder whether anyone can shed some light ...

The code below is contained in a single file named **freeze_example.py**

```
def f():
    print('Hello this is a subprocess')

if __name__ == '__mp_main__':
    
    print("Doing certain things")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    freeze_support()

    print("Doing certain other things")

    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The code has two if statements, one compares `__name__` to `__main__` and one compares `__name__` to `__mp_main__`

My goal is to perform different operations when freeze_example.py is imported by the main process and when it is imported by the subprocess.

When freeze_example.py is run from python command line this is the output:

```
__name__ is  __main__
Doing certain other things
__name__ is  __mp_main__
Doing certain things
Hello this is a subprocess
```

This reflects correctly the execution path one would expect. The `__name__` is different in the two different imports, allowing to determine which portion of code is executed in which case.

When I freeze freeze_example.py with the simple command "pyinstaller freeze_example.py" and I run the resulting executable under Windows, this is the output:

```
__name__ is  __main__
Doing certain other things
__name__ is  __main__
Hello this is a subprocess
```

Somehow `__name__` is the same in both imports (from the main process and from the subprocess) and so the body of `"if __name__ == '__mp_main__':"` is never executed.

Can anyone shed some light on why during the second import `__name__` is still `__main__` ?

The multiprocessing documentation does say very little about freeze_support(), besides the source code, is there any good source of information about this function?

I am using Python 3.6 and PyInstaller 4.7

Thanks for any tip,

Best Regards,

Andrea

Comment: I checked the definition of `freeze_support` to see if I could help... now I have some questions of my own.

Comment: Where does the line `__name__ is ...` get printed? I can't find it in your code.